# Cohomological propriety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p$, $\pi: \mathbf P^1_k\times\mathbf{A}_k^{n-1}\to\mathbf{A}_k^{n-1}$ with zero section $s$, $U\subset \mathbf P^1_k\times\mathbf{A}_k^{n-1} $ a Zariski open neighborhood of $D:=s(\mathbf{A}_k^{n-1})$, $\mathscr F$ a lisse $\mathbf{Q}_\ell$ sheaf on $U-D$, $j: U-s(\mathbf A^{n-1})\hookrightarrow U$ the open immersion of $\mathbf A^{n-1}$-schemes. If $\mathscr F$ is the restriction of a lisse sheaf $j_*\mathscr F$ on $U$, then cohomological purity tells us that $R^1j_*\mathscr F$ is lisse on $D$, locally isomorphic to the restriction of $j_*F$, with formation commuting with arbitrary base change $S’\to\mathbf A_k^{n-1}$, and $R^qj_*\mathscr F=0$ for $q>1$. If $\mathscr F$ is tamely ramified along $D$, then $(j,\mathscr F)$ is cohomologically proper in the language of Illusie in the appendix to *Th. finitude*; i.e. the formation of $Rj_*\mathscr F$ commutes with arbitrary base change $S’\to\mathbf A^{n-1}_k$.

Deligne-Laumon attach to the above situation a function $\Psi:D=s(\mathbf A^{n-1})\to\mathbf N$ given by
$$\Psi(s)=\operatorname{Sw}_{\overline s}(j_!\mathscr F|X_{\overline s}),$$
$\overline s$ being a geometric point centered on $s$. When this function is constant on $D$, their theorem says that $(U,j_!\mathscr F,\pi_U)$ is universally locally acyclic. (If $U=\mathbf P^1_k\times\mathbf{A}_k^{n-1}$, this implies that the $R^q\pi_!\mathscr F$ are lisse; it follows that the $R^q\pi_*\mathscr F$ are also, and both commute with arbitrary base change $S’\to\mathbf A^{n-1}_k$.)

For general $U$, even if $\Psi$ is constant on $D$, I do not believe the formation of the $Rj_*\mathscr F$ need commute with finite base change $S’\to\mathbf A^{n-1}_k$. My question is, are there additional hypotheses weaker than ‘$\mathscr F$ tamely ramified along $D$’ that will make this true?